# Django reading json and fetching data to bulk create with optimized approach and minimum resources

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, performance, django-models

Basically i was wondering if i could somehow use a single for loop to achieve a task

I am new to python and i am learning about the efficient ways to achieve stuff

This is the current scenario

```
json_dict = {
   items: [
   {'uuid': 'some uuid', 'quantity': 2},
   {'uuid': 'some uuid', 'quantity': 3},
   {'uuid': 'some uuid', 'quantity': 4}]
}
```

I am receiving this json and have to make a query to fetch each of these items based on the provided uuid. After fetching these items i have to create their entry in another model which is related to this model.

My approach is to separate the uuids and quantity into two separate lists through a for loop

```
   for item in json:
        item_uuids.append(item['uuid'])
        item_quantities.append(item['quantity'])
```

Fetch item objects

```
 q = Q()
 [q.add(Q(uuid=uuid), Q.OR) for uuid in item_uuids]
 items = model.objects.filter(q)
```

Then do a list comprehension

```
 item_objs = []
 [item_objs.append(ItemModel(uuid=uuid, quantity=quantity)) for uuid, quantity in zip(items, item_quantities)]
```

Then after all of this I make the final query

```
ModelA.objects.bulk_create(item_objs)
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve this, as it constantly disturbs me i might be following the wrong approach here.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do it wrong, but maybe just a little bit complex.
If I were you, I would first create a dictionary with given JSON, dictionary is one of the fastest type you can use.
You must change `json` variable name because there is an buildin module called json by the way.

```
json_items = {i.get('uuid'): i for i in _json}
```

And then for control db if given uuid list are exist:

```
exist_uuid_list = list(model.objects.filter(uuid__in=json_items.keys()).values_list('uuid', flat=True))
```

It gets only exist uuid list from db. If values_list has called, it just get given field from db, not all other fields, then it's fastest way.

Then bulk create:

```
model.objects.bulk_create([model(**item) for uuid, item in json_items.items() if uuid not in exist_uuid_list])
```

Actually only improvement is taking exist uuid from db.

Comment: Oh thank you for the answer, i should have been careful with the variable name json there is one thing i need the whole object in the bulk create after fetching it (the values list thing) as json currently doesn't contain all of the model object fields I would edit the question cause of its ambiguity .
Thanks one again